# why I keep receiving wrong data via i2c using esp32?

Tags: i2c, arduino-ide, freertos, esp-idf, attiny

I'm using a digispark as slave device that reads data from an analog sensor this is the code

```
#include "TinyWireS.h" //include the I2C library
#define I2C_SLAVE_ADDR  0x26 // define the I2C slave address of the device
int val = 0;

void requestEvent()
{
 val = analogRead(0); // read the analog value from the sensor
 TinyWireS.send((val >> 8) & 0xFF); // Send the high byte
 TinyWireS.send(val & 0xFF);        // Send the low byte // send the value over the I2C bus
}

void setup() {
    TinyWireS.begin(I2C_SLAVE_ADDR); //Initializes the I2C communication 
    TinyWireS.onRequest(requestEvent); // this function will respond to master requests
}

void loop() {
  TinyWireS_stop_check(); //checks for an I2C stop condition
}
```

and I'm trying to read the data via i2c bus on esp32(master device) using esp-idf framework so I created the first task for i2c initialization and the second task for data reading
but I keep getting the same wrong value on the monitor

```
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "driver/i2c.h"

#define I2C_MASTER_SCL_IO 22
#define I2C_MASTER_SDA_IO 21
#define I2C_MASTER_NUM I2C_NUM_0
#define I2C_MASTER_FREQ_HZ 100000 // I2C master clock frequency
#define I2C_MUX_ADDR 0x70 // I2C address of the multiplexer
#define ATTINY85_ADDR 0x26 // ATtiny85 I2C address
#define SENSOR_DATA_LENGTH 2
//task1
void initTask(void *voidparam)
{
 i2c_config_t conf;
    conf.mode = I2C_MODE_MASTER;
    conf.sda_io_num = I2C_MASTER_SDA_IO;
    conf.sda_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE;
    conf.scl_io_num = I2C_MASTER_SCL_IO;
    conf.scl_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE;
    conf.master.clk_speed = I2C_MASTER_FREQ_HZ;

    i2c_param_config(I2C_MASTER_NUM, &conf);
    i2c_driver_install(I2C_MASTER_NUM, conf.mode, 0, 0, 0);
    
    printf("I2C initialized\n");
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}
//task2
void i2cTask(void *voidparam)
{

    while (1) {
        i2c_cmd_handle_t cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();
        i2c_master_start(cmd);
        i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, (ATTINY85_ADDR << 1) | I2C_MASTER_READ, true);
        uint8_t data[SENSOR_DATA_LENGTH];
        i2c_master_read(cmd, data, SENSOR_DATA_LENGTH, I2C_MASTER_LAST_NACK); // Read all data bytes
        i2c_master_stop(cmd);
        i2c_master_cmd_begin(I2C_MASTER_NUM, cmd, pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
        i2c_cmd_link_delete(cmd);
        
        int16_t receivedValue = (data[0] << 8) | data[1]; // Combine two bytes
        
        printf("Received value: %d\n", receivedValue);

        vTaskDelay(1000 / pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
    }
}
void app_main(void)
{
    xTaskCreate(initTask,"initTask",10242,NULL,2,NULL);
    xTaskCreate(i2cTask,"i2cTask",10242,NULL,2,NULL);
}
```

I tried to change esp32 code

Comment: "I tried to change esp32 code" what changes did you make? What is the "wrong value" (what were you expecting to see), have you verified the device's address is correct and it is responding to that? Can you use a bus-pirate (or similar) to verify the device is operational?  Side note: I would not use a task to initialize the i2c service. Rather have a function that does the initialization called when first entering the i2c service task. Your while(1) loop then follows that initialization call.